# Notation for building ordered sets of zeros

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to define a lattice where each site is occupied by an ordered set of zeros. Later in the calculation, the zeros grow to nonnegative integers, but I need to start with zeros.  At the $i$th site, there should be $n_i$ zeros.  The set of zeros at the $i$th site is denoted $x_i$.  What is a nice way of denoting the set at the $i$th site?

$x_i =   ( j_k = 0   \;|\: k \in \mathbb{N} , k \le n_i)$

or

$x_i =   ( 0   \;|\: k \in \mathbb{N} , k \le n_i).$

The top expression with $j_k$ seems excessively complicated, but I don't think the bottom expression is allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply
$$ x_i = (\underbrace{0,0,\ldots,0}_{n_i\text{ zeros}}) $$
That's the most readable way to write it, and should therefore be preferred unless you have to placate someone who has harsh views on what is and isn't allowed in mathematical writing.

Second best, I think, would be something like
$$ x_i = (0)_{j\in\{1,2,\ldots, n_i\}} $$

If anything involving "$\ldots$" is disallowed, you'd have to write
$$ x_i = (0)_{1\le j\le n_i} $$
but then *human* readability begins to really suffer because it's not immediately clear that $j$ is meant to be an index variable.

Comment: Thanks. Say, am I supposed to give a "thumbs up" vote for your good answer. I can't se anything that allows me to do so.

Comment: @user73063: To upvote, click the double-up arrow at the upper left corner of the answer. However, you need to have 15 reputation points before it will do anything for you. (You get 5 points for each upvote on your question). What you can do right away, if you think the answer solves your problem, is to click on the outlined checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as "accepted". You can only do that for one answer to each of your questions, though, so it may be a good idea to wait a day or so, in case even better answers arrive later.